# Using Yahoo finance

Tags: java, yahoo-finance

I have a list of 1000 stocks of wich i am trying to get the price from yahoo finance. How ever the program seems to skip some stocks and does not fill it in. The code i am using is

```
     void display(String symbol) throws IOException
       {

                    URL yahoofin = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + symbol + "&f=l1kjm3m4r"); 
                    URLConnection yc = yahoofin.openConnection(); 

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream())); 
        String inputLine; 

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        { 

            System.out.println("ing= "+ing+" "+inputLine);
            info[ing]=inputLine;


        } 
        System.out.println("ing = "+ing);

        in.close(); 
    /* 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
       // log.error("Unable to get stockinfo for: " + symbol + ex); 
    } 
     */
 }
```

I keep passing new symbols from another function ten at a time. BUt  ing prints 7 sometimes.(that means stocks are skipped). Where am i going wrong.

Comment: Where does `ing` get set/modified?  What does it mean?

Comment: Just in case you are interested, I replied to a similar question but the code is in Excel / VBA: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9429975/829571

Comment: I did not understand anything in that link but can you tell me where i am going wrong?

Comment: ing is simply a test variable which counts the number of lines being read by the function

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a delay between your calls. Sometime Yahoo does not accept very high frequency requests and turns down some of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass more than one symbol per request (I think up to 50) seperated by "+".
This should imensely decrease the number of your requests.